# How to make drag&drop to move files instead of copy on Xfce desktop (Thunar 1.6.2)?

Tags: 12.10, xfce, desktop-environments, thunar

On the Xfce 12.10 desktop drag&drop to move files into a folder would copy them instead of moving (cut/paste) them.

I tend to have many files on the desktop and usually I grab them and put them in a folder for further use etc. I want to be able to do this by drag&drop, but at the present drag&drop makes a duplicate of them in that folder without removing them from their previous location.

In Xfce I use the default Thunar, and it handles the desktop.

---

### UPDATE:

**The question is limited to an older version of Thunar. In thunar 1.6.3, Xubuntu 14.04. drag&drop moves by default instead of just copy.**

Comment: Are you using Nautilus?

Comment: @Mitch - I do not (and will not). I use Thunar.

Comment: Thunar version?

Comment: Shift+drag works to move; plain drag just copies. This is with Thunar 1.6.2 and xfdesktop4 (on Lubuntu).

Comment: @vasa1 - thunar version 1.6.2. is it latest? are move/copy actions customizable?

Comment: 1.6.2 is what I got when I did `sudo apt-get install thunar`. I don't know about whether copy/move is customizable. Also, I won't go down that road myself because I don't know what else may be affected. I like it the way it is because having to press "shift" makes it less likely to do something by mistake.

Comment: this is no longer the case in thunar 1.6.3, Xubuntu 14.04. drag&drop moves by default instead of just copy

Comment: @cipricus Thunar 1.6.3 for Ubuntu 14.10 copies files if they are on same mounted ntfs device and moves them if they are on the same ext3 device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that this is what you want.

Well in Thunar , highlight all the files that you want to move, drag them with the right mouse button, and that will give you a pop up menu, that gives you the option to Move

[image]

Also you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, while dragging the files, and that will also move them.

Comment: i don't know if i made myself clear but i want this action **on** the desktop proper - not in a thunar window inside a folder.  (i am not sure what the correct term is for the 'desktop' as seen when opening the system, but that was what i meant by saying "on Xfce desktop", instead of "in Xfce desktop environment"). also, i cannot see the menu popup on the desktop or in a thunar window. there is no difference between left and right click dragging. but 'shift' does it